# Reload current route's model without Ember Data

Tags: ember.js

Ember Data has a `reload` method; I'm using a more basic approach ([using Ember objects](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-into-ember-js-part-3/)) to serve up my models, though.

I'd like a user to be able to reload the model for the current route via an action when e.g. a button is clicked. Is this possible without Ember Data?

Comment: If you're not using ember-data, you're probably using $.getJSON to get your data. So in order to get data again you have to make the same ajax call again via a route event (which you can DRY using a common method) or programmatically via a specific action method in  your controller.

Comment: How are you storing this state w/out ember-data? Do you have a model w/ a reopenClass (to hold a single array across the app globally?)

Comment: @ToranBillups Yes, I'm using Ember.Object and reopenClass to create a new method and returning that method from my route's model hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the async nature of the AJAX call I was making.

This didn't work:
`this.set('model', App.MyObject.findAll(value));`

I needed to allow the AJAX call to return the response, *then* populate the model:

```
var that = this;

App.MyObject.findAll(value).then(function(response) {
  that.set('model', response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really simple example of how I do it w/ your approach (notice the "clear").

You could invoke clear+find from your route / controller / whatever. I've also added a "beforeSend" to the $.ajax in some of my bigger apps (this will invoke the clear for you before the xhr is resolved)

```
App.Person.reopenClass({
    people: Ember.A([]),
    clear: function() {
        this.people = Ember.A([]);
    },
    add: function(hash) {
        var person = App.Person.create(hash);
        this.people.pushObject(person);
    },
    remove: function(person) {
        this.people.removeObject(person);
    },
    find: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/api/people', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(hash) {
                var person = App.Person.create(hash);
                Ember.run(self.people, self.people.pushObject, person);
            });
        }, this);
        return this.people;
    }
});
```